# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error in php while sending email

Tags: php, email, send

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
//Include Files
include 'config.php';
include 'jsonFormat.php';
include 'jsonDeliver.php';
$josn = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($josn, true);
$jsonresponse = array();
$Email=$data['signUp'][0]['email'];
echo $Email;

            $to=$Email;
            $subject='Email verification';
            $address = $to;
            $from='noreply@example.com';
            $body='hi';
            function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body,$from)
                {
                require_once('./smtp/class.phpmailer.php');
                //$from       = "from@gmail.com";
                $mail       = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->IsSMTP();            // use SMTP 
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;             // enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Host       = 'smtp.zoho.com'; // Amazon SES server, note "tls://" protocol
                $mail->Port       =  465;           // set the SMTP port
                $mail->Username   = 'noreply@example.com';  // SMTP  username
                $mail->Password   = 'noreply@123';  // SMTP password
                $mail->SetFrom('noreply@example.com');
                $mail->AddReplyTo('noreply@example.com');
                $mail->Subject    = $subject;
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                $address = $to;
                $mail->AddAddress($address,$to);
                        if(!$mail->Send())
                        {
                            //"Mailer Error". $mail->ErrorInfo;
                            echo "Mailer Error". $mail->ErrorInfo;
                        }   
                        else
                        {   $msg="your account activation link has sent to your mail please activate your account by clicking on givrn link";
                            echo $msg;
                            }                           
                }
                Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body,$from);     
?>
```

I was trying to send mail from php to a particular input mail id, but got stuck because its showing network error. I tried many ways to solve this issue but not able to find one. Please help me out to solve this issue. Is it a server problem?

Comment: We cannot magically guess what is happening on your systems. You are expected to be able to debug things yourself. We are only here to help with _specific_ questions, not with a general "does not work, tried all, fix it for me". The first step for you is to start looking into your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually read what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ or ask here.

Comment: FYI, the combination of CORS headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` is invalid per [the CORS specification, section 6.1.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests): *"The string "\*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials"*. Perhaps this is the network error to which you are referring?